# Why do I need to turn off frames for twinned matplotlib axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rendering, axes

When I have twinned axes in some (perhaps all, the visibility depends on the color I choose for my axes, with light ones showing the most effect) of my matplotlib plots, they appear "heavy" and sometimes with varying thicknesses unless I turn off the frame for all but one with

```
ax.set_frame_on(False)
```

Is this a known issue, or an issue that appears only in some renders (I see it most prominently using Agg to produce PDF)?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Because each frame gets drawn and the anti-alaising stacks

Comment: @tcaswell: That makes sense. For example, how prominent it is also depends on how much I zoom, and even on what tool I use to view the figure. Is using this technique generally done (or am I just being fussy)?

Comment: Can you make an issue on gh for this?  We probably should turn the frame off automatically when you use `twin*`.  Currently I think it only makes the the patch invisible.

Comment: @tcaswell: Sure. Can you give me a link so I put it in the right place?